# JButton with image background and text alignment

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've got (again) a problem: i got a jbutton with an image on background, but when i want to put some text on it, it will apears on the right side of background, not in button, but aside...
Here is working code, you must only link some image :)

```
package program;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Program {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JButton button;
    private static Image buttonImage;
    private static ImageIcon buttonIcon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200,100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        String imgUrl = "images/";
        try {
            buttonImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imgUrl+"img.png"));    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Program.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        buttonIcon = new ImageIcon(buttonImage);
        button = new JButton("TEST", buttonIcon);
        panel.add(button);
        button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 146, 67);
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never set the background,you'v set the icon of the button

Comment: hm, so, how can i set the image as background? :(

Answer (score 3):

Here are 4 ways to display text on an image:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LabelImageText extends JPanel
{
    public LabelImageText()
    {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.ORANGE, 100, 100) );
        label1.setText( "Easy Way" );
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        add( label1 );

        //

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.YELLOW, 200, 150) );
        label2.setLayout( new BoxLayout(label2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
        add( label2 );

        JLabel text = new JLabel( "More Control" );
        text.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
        label2.add( text );
        label2.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(10) );

        //

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.GREEN, 200, 150) );
        label3.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        add( label3 );

        JLabel text3 = new JLabel();
        text3.setText("<html><center>Text<br>over<br>Image<center></html>");
        text3.setLocation(20, 20);
        text3.setSize(text3.getPreferredSize());
        label3.add( text3 );

        //

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel( new ColorIcon(Color.CYAN, 200, 150) );
        add( label4 );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Add some text that will wrap at your preferred width");
        textPane.setEditable( false );
        textPane.setOpaque(false);
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        textPane.setBounds(20, 20, 75, 100);
        label4.add( textPane );
    }

    public static class ColorIcon implements Icon
    {
        private Color color;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public ColorIcon(Color color, int width, int height)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getIconWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

        public int getIconHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelImageText");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new LabelImageText() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StringTest extends JFrame
        implements ActionListener
{
  private JTextField input, result;
  private int i;

  public StringTest()
  {
    super("String test");
    i=0;

    Box box1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box1.add(new JLabel(" Input:"));
    box1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box1.add(new JLabel("Result:"));

    input = new JTextField(40);
    input.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    input.addActionListener(this);
    input.selectAll();

    result = new JTextField(40);
    result.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    result.setEditable(false);

    Box box2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box2.add(input);
    box2.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box2.add(result);

    Box box3 = Box.createHorizontalBox(); 
    box3.add(box1);
    box3.add(box2);

    Box box4 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    JButton new_game = new JButton("NEW GAME");
    JLabel game_title =new JLabel("***Welcome to Hangman Game***");
    box4.add(game_title);

    box4.add(box3);
    box4.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box4.add(box3);
    box4.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box4.add(new_game);
    new_game.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(box4);
    //c.add(box2);
   // c.add(ok_button);c.add(ok1_button);
    input.requestFocus();
  }



  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

    String str = input.getText();

    result.setText(str);
    if (i%2==0)
       result.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    else
       result.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    input.selectAll();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    StringTest window = new StringTest();
    window.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the JButton Alignment Failed together with JLabel. the above code new_game button not in the center. But if you remove the JLabel game_title, it works. So it is a bug in the swing.

Comment: Centainly you can add another level box5 to seperate JButton and JLabel, then it works.