# How to set image on jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Hi i am creating a java desktop application where i i am having a `JLabel` i want to  put more then 1 image on that `JLabel` and also want to write some text on that j label

```
  ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("Images/YourCompanyLogo.png");
  ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("Images/Your.png");
  // In init() method write this code
  jLabelYourCompanyLogo.setIcon(iconLogo);
```

How can I achieve this?

I want to add these 2 icons to `JLabel` after hello

Thanks in advance

Comment: A label can only display 1 icon. Make a single image out of these two images, or use 2 labels.

Comment: can i use 1 image with text

Comment: @JBNizet Or override its `paintComponent` method to make it display multiple images

Comment: _"can i use 1 image with text"_. Yes. `setIcon` `setText`. Use `setHorizontalTextPosition` and `setVerticalTextPosition` to set the text's position relative to the icon.

Comment: @peeskillet yes i did this i but its does not meet  with my need

Comment: i m using netbeans gui

Comment: @BackSlash but then, you're basically transforming the JLabel into a custom component, and you could as well use a JComponent.

Comment: Do you mean you want text _over_ the icon?

Comment: @peeeskillet no i want text   and then image eg hello  image

Comment: 1) What's wrong with using two labels? 2) I told you how to position the text. `label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEADING)` to get the text on the left. By default it is on the right.

Comment: i am not having prob in using 2 label

Comment: but i want one lable if it hapeen it will be good

Comment: _"i am not having prob in using 2 label"_. Then I really don't see the problem.

Comment: There's nothing special about using just one label. Use what you see fit. Swing is at your disposal. If you want _"one"_ component, wrap the two labels in a `JPanel`. There's your one component to do with whatever you see fit.

Comment: @peeskillet  how to set border for jframe

Comment: `JFrame` has no `setBorder`. Use a `JPanel` as the contentpane and set the border to the panel

Comment: can i use rectange as  a border

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/), which allows you to combine two or more Icons into one.

Or, just create a JPanel (using an appropriate layout manager) and add two JLabels to the panel.

> also want to write some text on that j label

See: [Image Background and Text Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21270967/131872) for 4 ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "(Insert your path here)"
```

You have to move your images into your project which means the project where everything your code and stuff is saved in .
Then u create another folder f.e called res which stands for ressource and where u save all your pictures you want to load.
Then if you got this it looks like this:

```
 String path = "/res/(Your picture name DONT FORGET .png or .jpg ending)"
```

Picture should be png or jpg!

Then back coding:
U create a new URL called url and other stuff

```
Url url;
ImageIcon ii;
Image image;
```

Then in your constructor of your class u write this:

```
url = getClass().getResource(path);
ii = new ImageIcon(url);
image = ii.getImage();
```

Then you need a second method which you call

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     g.drawImage(url,imageX,imageY,null);
}
```

And at the top of your class you import

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```